Proper LEAN_PATH environment variable value for Windows Lean Visual Studio project?
I have a Lean 4 test project in C:\Temp\MyProject I open with Visual Studio. In that directory, I have a Main.lean file. And, in C:\Temp\MyProject\MySub, I have a MyDefs.lean.
In Main.lean, I try to import MySub.MyDefs
Visual Studio tells me object file 'C:\Temp\MyProject\MySub\MyDefs.olean' of module MySub.MyDefs does not exist. I can't find a MyDefs.olean file in my project directory.
Here, one suggests setting an environment variable LEAN_PATH which I did with C:\Temp\MyProject, but to no avail.
What would be the proper value for this environment variable? Or, does the issue lie elsewhere?
Update
Requested troubleshooting information:
**Operating system**: Windows_NT (release: 10.0.19045)
**CPU architecture**: x64
**CPU model**: 4 x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
**Available RAM**: 8.50 GB

**Curl installed**: true
**Git installed**: true
**Elan**: Reasonably up-to-date (version: 3.1.1)
**Lean**: Reasonably up-to-date (version: 4.9.0-rc2)
**Project**: Valid Lean project (path: c:\Temp\MyProject)

-------------------------------------

**Elan toolchains**: 
```
installed toolchains
--------------------

leanprover/lean4:nightly-2024-04-24
leanprover/lean4:stable (default)
leanprover/lean4:v4.8.0-rc2
leanprover/lean4:v4.9.0-rc2


active toolchain
----------------


leanprover/lean4:v4.9.0-rc2 (overridden by '\\?\C:\Temp\MyProject\lean-toolchain')

Lean (version 4.9.0-rc2, x86_64-w64-windows-gnu, commit 7ed9b73f4d4c, Release)
```


I'm sorry, Lean users aren't very active on this SE. Come to https://leanprover.zulipchat.com and you'll get a quick answer! :-)

Where did you get the idea that the Lean users are not very active here? They are just more active over at Zulip.

The issue lies elsewhere: you should never need to set LEAN_PATH by hand. Are you opening your project folder in VSCode (rather than an individual file)? This should be the folder containing your lakefile.toml (or lakefile.lean).
If you click on the "∀" symbol in the top right in VSCode, select "Troubleshooting: Show Setup Information", and come tell us the results on https://leanprover.zulipchat.com, someone can probably fix your problem!

Please stop siphning people to Zulip. Firstly, it is not polite. Secondly, the answers recorded here are findable by Google, wherease Zulip is a walled garden with an awful search facility. Thirdly, thank you for your answer.

At the very least I would expect you to invite the OP also to Zulip. But you're telling them to abandon this forum.

To be fair, for this sort of debugging which usually needs interaction, SO is not ideal… However, once a solution has been found it would be nice if the OP (or someone else) would come back here to make the answer public and findable
